# $.parseJSON(data, true) throws

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-ajax

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5.
I am trying to deserialize dates coming from the server in JSON format. The JSON arrives and when I try to deserialize the dates the debugger just stops and don't show any errors other the in the console, which I can't understand.
This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/GetDates',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (dates) {        
       var date = dates[0];
        var desDate = $.parseJSON(date, true);
        console.log(desDate);
    }

});

});
```

Here are some pics on the errormessage and that a have data coming in.

[image]

[image]

Here is a link to the docs I have been looking at. [Docs](http://erraticdev.blogspot.se/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html)

Comment: What do want the output to be like?

Comment: The JSON **is already parsed** ! That's what setting the `dataType` to `json` does, it parses it for you. Parsing it again will always throw errors.

Comment: Something like: 2014/06/06. I know perhaps I would have to put the dates thru more formatting but as of now i cant get it passt JSON -> JS

Comment: Again, `dates` is already parsed, and `dates[0]` is the string `/Date(14984....)/` and that's not valid JSON and can't be parsed as such

Comment: hhmm. ok nice! What would I have to do to get the parsed dates to look something llike 2017/06/06

Comment: You'd have to remove everything but the timestamp and then use that timestamp to create a date object, and then get the year, month etc.

Comment: Something like `var d = new Date( +date.replace(/\D/g, '') )`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works! I appreciateyou taking the time to answer my question. I will definitely read up on ajax and JSON. If you make your answer the official answer I´ll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data returned from the ajax call is already parsed, so `dates` is an array containing strings, and `dates[0]` is the string`/Date(14984....)/` etc.

To parse the string, remove everything but the numbers, and use that timestamp to create a Date object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : '/Home/GetDates',
        dataType    : "json",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (dates) {        
            var d    = dates[0];
            var unix = +d.replace(/\D/g, '');
            var date = new Date(unix);

            var desDate = date.getFullYear() + '/' + 
                          (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + 
                          date.getDate();

            console.log(desDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This does what I want. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the JavaScript inside your string variable as

```
var dateVar  = eval(dates[0]);
```

This will give you the date but not in a proper format which you want. For the proper format user either `moment.js` or simply create your own lines of code like

```
var finalDate = new Date(dateVar).toISOString().split('T')[0];
console.log(finalDate);
```

The `new Date()` is again needed here so that we can make use of `toISOString()` and get the proper date format.

Comment: Thank you. ´ll look in to it soon. On the run. right now.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are referring to this [jQuery parseJSON automatic date conversion for Asp.net and ISO date strings](http://erraticdev.blogspot.it/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html) you need to include the jQuery extension defined there.

Indeed, in jQuery [parseJSON(jsonString)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) accepts only one argument while you are using an extension.

Moreover, your dates variable is an array of string, and not a json string.

```js
//
// Look at the end....
//

/*
 * jQuery.parseJSON() extension (supports ISO & Asp.net date conversion)
 *
 * Version 1.0 (13 Jan 2011)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Robert Koritnik
 * Licensed under the terms of the MIT license
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function ($) {

    // JSON RegExp
    var rvalidchars = /^[\],:{}\s]*$/;
    var rvalidescape = /\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g;
    var rvalidtokens = /"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g;
    var rvalidbraces = /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g;
    var dateISO = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:[.,]\d+)?Z/i;
    var dateNet = /\/Date\((\d+)(?:-\d+)?\)\//i;

    // replacer RegExp
    var replaceISO = /"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:[.,](\d+))?Z"/i;
    var replaceNet = /"\\\/Date\((\d+)(?:-\d+)?\)\\\/"/i;

    // determine JSON native support
    var nativeJSON = (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) ? true : false;
    var extendedJSON = nativeJSON && window.JSON.parse('{"x":9}', function (k, v) {
                return "Y";
            }) === "Y";

    var jsonDateConverter = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof(value) === "string") {
            if (dateISO.test(value)) {
                return new Date(value);
            }
            if (dateNet.test(value)) {
                return new Date(parseInt(dateNet.exec(value)[1], 10));
            }
        }
        return value;
    };

    $.extend({
        parseJSON: function (data, convertDates) {
            /// <summary>Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.</summary>
            /// <param name="data" type="String">The JSON string to parse.</param>
            /// <param name="convertDates" optional="true" type="Boolean">Set to true when you want ISO/Asp.net dates to be auto-converted to dates.</param>

            if (typeof data !== "string" || !data) {
                return null;
            }

            // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
            data = $.trim(data);

            // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
            // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
            if (rvalidchars.test(data
                            .replace(rvalidescape, "@")
                            .replace(rvalidtokens, "]")
                            .replace(rvalidbraces, ""))) {
                // Try to use the native JSON parser
                if (extendedJSON || (nativeJSON && convertDates !== true)) {
                    return window.JSON.parse(data, convertDates === true ? jsonDateConverter : undefined);
                }
                else {
                    data = convertDates === true ?
                            data.replace(replaceISO, "new Date(parseInt('$1',10),parseInt('$2',10)-1,parseInt('$3',10),parseInt('$4',10),parseInt('$5',10),parseInt('$6',10),(function(s){return parseInt(s,10)||0;})('$7'))")
                                    .replace(replaceNet, "new Date($1)") :
                            data;
                    return (new Function("return " + data))();
                }
            } else {
                $.error("Invalid JSON: " + data);
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);




var date = '{"date": "\\/Date(1498435200000)\\/"}';
var desDate = $.parseJSON(date, true);
console.log(desDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I Will definitely look try this one out. Been at this problem for some time now and was getting tired. Wasn't looking close enough to se I was missing pars of it. Thank you for your help!